# Crystal Report Group Expert not finding all fields

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I created a stored procedure with the following fields : Name, Surname, DateOfBirth, Age.
When I want to group then by Surname using the Group Expert it only displays Age as an available field. The Group Expert can;t seem to find the other fields and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Can you give us the stored procedure?

Comment: Never mind I solved it by creating a formula left({GetWorksheet;1.Name}, 100) this selects all the characters to the left of the field value up until the 100th character. The group Expert picks up the function

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer so other people can see it.

Comment: Will post my answer in about 8 hours. Since i have a under 10 rep score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by creating a formula in crystal reports:

left({GetWorksheet;1.Name}, 100)

It selects all the characters to the left of the field value up until the 100th character. The Group Expert finds the formula, so i used this to group my fields.